# ggpmisc clearing up confusion about summarized data lengths

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpmisc

I am getting this  error message "Error in data.frame(mean_Flow, dates) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 84, 30274" and I know it is confused about which date function I want it to pull but I'm not sure how to clear it up.  I want the data summarized as yearly mean. It is plotting this properly, but not producing the correct stat_poly_eq. I would appreciate any help!

```
library(dataRetrieval)
library("plyr")
siteNo = "02202500"
pCode = "00060"

daily = readNWISdv(siteNo, pCode, "1800-10-01","2020-09-30", statCd="00003")
daily = renameNWISColumns(daily)
dates= format(as.Date(daily$Date), format = "%Y")
ddply(daily, .(site_no, dates), summarise,
      mean_Flow = mean(Flow)*(0.0283168))

library(dplyr)
library(ggpmisc) # for dealing with stat equations
library(ggplot2) # for making plots 
library(lubridate) # for working with dates
library(scales) #for working with date_format

df=data.frame(mean_Flow, dates)
head(df)
df$dates = as.Date(df$dates, format = "%Y")
my.formula = df$mean_Flow ~ df$dates

p1=ggplot(data = df,aes(dates, mean_Flow)) +
  geom_line(group = 1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula,
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(y))~`=`~",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")))+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x="", y=(expression(Discharge~(m^{3}~s^{-1}))))+
  scale_x_date(breaks = "5 year", labels = date_format("%Y"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
p1
```

Comment: never used `stat_poly_eq`, but try with `y ~ x`

Comment: I fixed it by directly mapping to the ddply. Thanks for your help!                                              
            df=ddply(daily, .(site_no, dates), summarise,
      mean_Flow = mean(Flow)*(0.0283168))

Answer (score 0):

The formula passed to `stat_poly_eq()` is evaluated within the "data" as seen within the ggplot layer: i.e., rather than using the names of the variable in `df`, the names of the aesthetics to which the variables have been mapped to must be used. In other words, @Richard Telford guessed correctly what the problem is. This behaviour is identical to that of `stat_smooth()`, for which the code above uses the default value `y ~ x` for `formula`.